# Reverse col and rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2016

I have to create query, to reverse rows and cols correct. I am using MS SQL SERVER 2016.

This is what I have:

```
Row_ID | Group_ID | Group_Status | MemberRole | name
2807   | 10568    | accept       | chairman   | Rajah
2808   | 10568    | accept       | member     | Vaughan
2812   | 10568    | accept       | secretary  | Susan
```

This is what I need:

```
Group_ID | Status | Chairman | Secretary | Member1 | Member2 | Member3 | ... | Member20 
10568    | Accept | Rajah    | Susan     | Vaughan | Kane    | Oprah   | ... | Imelda
```

(users with member role can be between 0-20)

Probably I should use pivot, but I have no idea how.

Ok, I have this code:

```
 SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT group_id, 
       group_status, 
       memberRole, 
       name
FROM DataGroup
) dataSource PIVOT(MAX(name) FOR memberRole IN([chairman], 
                                           [secretary], 
                                           [member])) pivotTab;
```

But I losing rows with members (get only one member), how to extract them to columns?

Comment: I need static col number(20), but currently I'm losing data about members. Is it posible to put rest members to next columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with a *unioned* query:

Some mockup (please provide such a dummy table with your sample data yourself in your next question):

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Row_ID INT,Group_ID INT,Group_Status VARCHAR(100),MemberRole VARCHAR(100),[name] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (2807,10568,'accept','chairman','Rajah')
,(2808,10568,'accept','member','Vaughan')
,(2812,10568,'accept','secretary','Susan')
,(2899,10568,'accept','member','Onemore');
```

--The query

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT Group_ID
          ,Group_Status
          ,[name]
          ,MemberRole
    FROM @mockup 
    WHERE MemberRole IN('chairman','secretary')

    UNION ALL
    SELECT Group_ID
          ,Group_Status
          ,[name]
          ,CONCAT('Member',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Group_ID ORDER BY Row_ID))  
    FROM @mockup 
    WHERE MemberRole='member'
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX([name]) FOR MemberRole IN(Chairman,Secretary,Member1,Member2,Member3 /*add as many as you need*/)
) p;
```

The result

```
Group_ID    Group_Status    Chairman    Secretary   Member1     Member2     Member3
10568       accept          Rajah       Susan       Vaughan     Onemore     NULL
```

In short:

The first part of the query will Just pick the two fix names.

The second part will pick the members and number them sorted by their Row_ID.

The `PIVOT` will then transform this to a single row, using the column `MemberRole` for the new column names.

You will have to think about some more things:

- What if not all the lines are `accepted`?
- What of there are many groups?

If you need help, you can comeback with a new question. Happy Coding!

Comment: "please provide such a dummy table..." I see it's finally catching. It would be nice if someway we wouldn't have to write that anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select group_id, group_status,
       max(case when member_role = 'chairman' then name end) as chairman,
       max(case when member_role = 'secretary' then name end) as secretary,
       max(case when member_role = 'member' and seqnum = 1 then name end) as member_01,
       max(case when member_role = 'member' and seqnum = 2 then name end) as member_02,
       . . .
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group_id, member_role order by row_id) as seqnum
      from @mockup m
     ) m
group by group_id, group_status;
```

I find conditional aggregation to be much more flexible than `pivot`.  This is an example of the situation where the query is simpler.